# Json get titles of valuetypes not objects

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

in javascript  getting schema (json result) as attached image and then I am iterating to get column names as below in javascipt.

I want to iterate / get titles for only value type discard type is object (example orders, customerDemographics) , how can I achieve this.

I want all properties that are not type of object

```
for (field in schema) {
var title = field.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1");                    
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This almost seems like a reflection question.  Perhaps you should post the code that gets the 'schema' object.  An image doesn't really have enough context.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pick out all of the properties that are of type object?

Comment: I want all properties that are not type of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (field in schema) {
    if (typeof schema[field] !== "object"){
       // property schema[field] is not an object
    }           
}
```

I think the if statement above does what you want.  It will pick out all properties that are not of type object.

One other thing.  In the code you are implicitly defining the variable field (if it's not defined in another block of code that you haven't posted).  This is considered bad practice.  I would change this line to:

```
for(var field in schema)
```

Comment: how can i make this as answered

Comment: Click the tick next to my answer